# Finetunng a deep network

Tags: regression, hyperparameter

Can we perform fine tuning using the pre-trained weight file when the network is slightly changed? 
I have changed the CNN from classification to regression network and rest of the network is the same. I have a pretrained model file for classification.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. Usually, when you switch from classification to regression, you may "decapitate" the CNN by chopping off the top few layers including the softmax, and putting on new fully connected layers you need for regression.

Therefore you would be using the pretrained weights for the rest of the layers, but you would need to start training the new layers you tacked on from scratch.

The procedure for doing this in practice depends very much on which framework you are using. In keras, I believe you can just load the entire model with all the weights, and then just pop off the top few layers and add on your new layers. In tensorflow, you want to build your new regression first, then load only the weights from the old layers, making use of variable scopes to specify which weights should be restored.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#choosing_which_variables_to_save_and_restore

Comment: I am using caffe as the framework.
I want to use SqueezeNet (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07360.pdf) as the network. But SqueezeNet has no fully connected layer.